# How to update existing nested attribute w/ no FK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Assuming User has_one :subscription, Subscription belongs_to :user, and I am using accepts_nested_attributes_for to nest subscription attributes into the user creation form, what is the best way to locate and update and existing subscription (if it exists) based on User.email == Subscription.email?

Note that existing subscriptions could have user_id = nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you want to do is use the email as the foreign key:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subscription, :foreign_key => "email", :primary_key => "email"
end
```

Comment: Hrm, yeah...I thought about doing that.  Let me toy around with that idea.  Thanks.

Comment: I've done it occasionally.  Works pretty well aside from being a natural key, which means you're going to run into problems when users want to change their email addresses.  just make sure you've got an index on the email for both tables.

Comment: Ok, I've setup the associations but I'm still getting duplicate records.  I have update_only => true on the accepts_nested_attributes_for.  Any ideas?

Comment: The issue may be that the subscription email is not being delivered via the form, but rather set as... before_save { self.email = user.email if user }.  Not sure...

Comment: if that's the case, you'll probably need some custom logic in your controller to handle it.  nested attributes may not be the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that this would need to be split into a two-step process:

1. Locate the user you want to update.
2. Locate a subscription (if any) with the user's e-mail address, Set the subscription on the user to this record.
3. Update the user as normal. Since the association is now present (i.e. user.subscription will not be nil), the subscription records will update correctly.